# Adjust kinect camera angle using Kinect sdk for windows v 2.0

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

In Kinect SDK v1.x there used to be an `ElevationAngle` property on `KinectSensor`
object. It is not present in Kinect SDK v2.0 anymore.

Does anybody have an idea on how to adjust kinect camera elevation angle using Kinect SDK for windows v2.x and of course Kinect for Xbox One?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Kinect v2, Microsoft increased the field of view and removed the tilt motor; so it's not possible to adjust the elevation angle anymore. But the good news is that with the expanded field of view, you can see as much as the Kinect 1 without having to move the sensor.

Look at this article, there is a table that clearly shows that Kinect 2 has no tilt motor: http://zugara.com/how-does-the-kinect-2-compare-to-the-kinect-1.

This article mentions it too, although the author missed the fact that the expanded field of view removes the need for the tilt motor: http://123kinect.com/everything-kinect-2-one-place/43136/.

This one highlights that fact: http://www.develop-online.net/news/next-xbox-leak-reveals-kinect-2-specs/0114096.

Comment: I feel silly I didn't check myself if there is a tilt motor on Kinect 2 sensor. Thank you.